# ispac File size is getting big in SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-server-2012

I am using SSIS version 2012 , and in that I am using ispac file for deploying my SSIS packages (the packages are added dynamically to this file), and the size of ispac file is increasing after each run , that is making execution of SSIS package very slow .
(e.g. loading it to Database (CSV to DB) takes 3 mins. (with ispac file size 2 mb) and same loading (same csv to Database) takes 21 mins (with ispac file size 5 mb) )

1. I wanted to know how can I stop ispac file size to increase .
2. How can I reduce if it increases , control the size .
3. or what is the reason the SSIS Package execution is slow .

Comment: what is total size of all your packages in your solution and what is the size of ispac file? you can rename the .ispac file and give it a .zip extension, and extract it to see all the files inside. This should give you a idea about the size of the ispac file

Comment: there are total 100 SSIS packages in the ispac file , and the size of ispac file is 5.1 MB, it takes 21 minutes to execute one SSIS package with this file size , but it takes 3 minutes when ispac file size is 2MB

Comment: That size seems normal. If you keep adding packages to your solution the size of ispac will grow. It is basically a zip file.

Comment: ok, but the total time taken to execute SSIS package(21 min.) is a concern, which with smaller ispac file takes 3 minutes , any suggestions ...?

Comment: You are barking at the wrong tree my friend. Analyze your packages to find the reason why it is taking more time. It is not connected to ispac file, that much I can tell you.

Answer (score 0):

An .ispac file is no more than a zip archive with all project items - packages, connection managers and metadata describing it. To you questions:

1. To stop ispac file grow - stop adding new packages to the project. You mentioned that packages are added dynamically to the project - stop adding packages or remove obsolete packages from the project.
2. To control size of an ispac file - control size of all project items listed above.

To your problem with lengthy SSIS package execution time - it has little to do with ispac file size. Simply deploy ispac to SSIS Catalog (SSISDB) and run package from it; package run will not require an ispac deployment.
Debugging a modified package in Visual Studio requires project update i.e. ispac being deployed to the SSIS Catalog. This is a price to pay for SSIS Project approach, and that is the reason why you should restrict your projects in size.

Comment: if I say that when I load a file with ispac size 2 MB it takes 3 minutes and same file load takes 21 mins , when ispac size is 5.2 MB , do you see any solutions

Comment: @GouravVerma, deploy time depends on many factors - how many packages are you deploying, its size etc. In general, the less packages you have in ispac - the less time its deploy will take. You can check for index recommendations for SSISDB DB from DMVs; I would not expect much from it.

Comment: I think here is some confusion, Loading a file means , loading it to Database (CSV to DB) takes 3 mins. (with ispac file size 2 mb)                and (same csv to Database) 21 mins (with ispac file size 5 mb)

Comment: @GouravVerma, if your ispac is bigger - you have more packages, more actions to do. Therefore, processing and load time can be longer. Without knowledge of your package and project structure - it is hardly possible to tell the reason.